# Сортировка datagridview столбца начиная со 2 строки

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть некий набор данных который биндится к датагриду. Здесь все ок. Но появилась необходимость отсортировать в этом гриде строки по определенному столбцу. например в порядке возрастания отсортировать записи с ценой, НО начиная со 2 -ой строки. Т.е. первая строка должна быть зафиксирована, а все остальные строки начиная со 2-ой должны быть отсортированы. Если бы не условие что со второй строки, то все просто:

```
Grid1.Sort(Поле,Порядок сортировки (asc,desc));
```

Но как сделать с условием, не могу понять.

Comment: Напишите кастомный компаратор. А так как используется привязка, то нужно сортировать источник данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: пример работы]

Это вьюха

```
public partial class MainView : Form, IMainView
{
    private BindingSource _bsPeople = new BindingSource();

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetBindings();

        this.CenterToScreen();
        this.Text = nameof(WFApp1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Привязки
    /// </summary>
    private void SetBindings()
    {
        _dataGridViewPeople.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        _dataGridViewPeople.DataSource = _bsPeople;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Список людей
    /// </summary>
    public List<Person> People
    {
        get => _bsPeople.List.Cast<Person>().ToList();
        set
        {
            _bsPeople.Clear();
            foreach (var item in value)
            {
                _bsPeople.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Привязка к событию клика по названию столбца
    /// </summary>
    private IFormsEventHandler<string> _SortPeople;
    public IFormsEventHandler<string> SortPeople
    {
        set
        {
            if (_SortPeople != null) return;
            _SortPeople = value;

            _dataGridViewPeople.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (_bsPeople.Count == 0) return;
                if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) return; //клик по "н/п"

                //получаем название свойства по названю столбца
                string cName = GetColumnName(e.ColumnIndex);
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cName)) return;
                //вызов обработчика
                _SortPeople.Handler(s, cName);
            };
        }
    }

    private string GetColumnName(int columnIndex)
    {
        string result = String.Empty;

        switch (columnIndex)
        {
            case 1:
                result = nameof(ColumnLastName).Replace("Column", "");
                break;
            case 2:
                result = nameof(ColumnFirstName).Replace("Column", ""); ;
                break;
            case 3:
                result = nameof(ColumnCity).Replace("Column", ""); ;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Это презентер

```
public class MainPresenter : IMainPresenter
{
    public IMainView View { get; private set; }

    //ctor
    public MainPresenter(IMainView view)
    {
        View = view ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(view));

        View.SortPeople = new ParamEventHandler(OnSortPeople);
        LoadData();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обработка события клика по столбцу, сортировка
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="columnName">имя столбца-свойства</param>
    public void OnSortPeople(string columnName)
    {
        //запоминаем первого (первая строка в гриде)
        var firstPerson = View.People.First();

        //получаем данные и сортируем, в реальности сортировку можно
        //сделать и с помощью соотв.запроса к БД
        var people = Program.Context.GetPeople();
        people.Sort(new PersonComparer(columnName));

        //находим такого же и удаляем
        var samePerson = people.Single(p => p.Id == firstPerson.Id);
        people.RemoveAt(people.IndexOf(samePerson));

        //новая коллекция
        var nPeople = new List<Person>();
        //добавляем первого
        nPeople.Add(firstPerson);
        //добавляем остальных отсортированных
        nPeople.AddRange(people);

        //пронумеруем
        SetOrderNumbers(nPeople);
        //отобразим
        View.People = nPeople;
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        var people = Program.Context.GetPeople();
        //пронумеруем
        SetOrderNumbers(people);
        //отобразим
        View.People = people;
    }

    private void SetOrderNumbers(List<Person> people)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < people.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            people[i - 1].OrderNumber = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Кастомный компаратор такой

```
public class PersonComparer : IComparer<Person>
{
    private readonly string _propName;

    //ctor
    public PersonComparer(string propName)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propName)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propName));
        _propName = propName;
    }

    public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
    {
        int result = 0;

        switch (_propName)
        {
            case "FirstName":
                result = x.FirstName.CompareTo(y.FirstName);
                break;
            case "LastName":
                result = x.LastName.CompareTo(y.LastName);
                break;
            case "City":
                result = x.City.CompareTo(y.City);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Весь пример можно скачать [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/DQinHFlw8IpW0g)